# How to get values in a column of dictionary-like string?

Tags: python, pandas, string, dataframe, dictionary

I have a dataframe with a column that looks like this:

```
d = {'genres': 
      [ [
          {"id": 10751,"name": "Family"}, 
          {"id": 16, "name": "Animation"}, 
          {"id": 12, "name": "Adventure"},           
          {"id": 35, "name": "Comedy"}],
        [
          {"id": 878, "name": "Science Fiction"}, 
          {"id": 12, "name": "Adventure"}, 
          {"id": 53, "name": "Thriller"}]]}

df_input = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

I need the following output:

```
d = {'genres': 
      [ ["Family", "Animation", "Adventure", "Comedy",],
        ["Science Fiction", "Adventure", "Thriller"]]}

df_output = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

Comment: whats the input is it a dict?

Answer (score 2):

You can extract values from dictionary by list comprehension in [`Series.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.apply.html):

```
df_input['genres'] = df_input['genres'].apply(lambda x:[y['name'] for y in x])
print (df_input)
                                   genres
0  [Family, Animation, Adventure, Comedy]
1  [Science Fiction, Adventure, Thriller]
```

Or by nested list comprehension:

```
df_input['genres'] = [[y['name'] for y in x] for x in df_input['genres']]
```

EDIT: If real data contsins stings, not dicts use:

```
import json, ast

df_input['genres'] = df_input['genres'].apply(lambda x:[y['name'] for y in ast.literal_eval(x)])
```

Or:

```
df_input['genres'] = df_input['genres'].apply(lambda x:[y['name'] for y in json.loads(x)])
```

Comment: I still have an error (string indices must be integers)  when I apply this piece of code to a whole dataset

Comment: https://www.kaggle.com/tmdb/tmdb-movie-metadata?select=tmdb_5000_movies.csv here is a dataset

Comment: Error - the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not list.

Comment: Morevoer - the thing is some rows are empty lists - [], so lambda funtion may not work for some rows

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this with **pandas**, it is possible with **apply** method
Try creating a function to return "name" values for each element,

```
>>> def getNames(x):
        return [xi["name"] for xi in x]
```

Now, all you need to do is apply it on a column in your dataframe,

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

>>> d_out = df['genres'].apply(getNames) # This returns the output that you want

>>> df_output = pd.DataFrame(data=d_out, columns=["genres"])

    genres
0  [Family, Animation, Adventure, Comedy]
1  [Science Fiction, Adventure, Thriller]
```

There could be shorter ways.